# Rails Bootstrap Modal Remote True does not work in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Executive Summary

1. I have Bootstrap Modal on a Rails 4 Server I have created
2. This Modal is used to submit a NEW post via remote: true
3. I get an error during the Form Submission saying remote true doesn't work.
4. The form can actually submit successful WITHOUT the remote true but it isn't ajax.
5. What is wrong with my remote: true line. It is a direct cut and paste.

Dear Friends,

So I have been spending two days on this problem. I have a Bootstrap Modal that I want to use to allow for new submissions. I want this to be done via ajax, and from all the documentation form_for() object should be passed at :remote => true.

I am able to get my form to work without the remote true enabled, but when I place it in my form_for,  It no longer works and I get a syntax error as listed below.

Please help.

applicaton.html.erb in Layouts

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %> 
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require masonry/jquery.infinitescroll.min
//= require_tree .
```

This is the HTML file that generates the Modal

```
<div id="largeModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Submission</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <%= render 'formnew' %>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my formnew.html.erb (This is where the problem is)

```
<%= form_for (@item, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @item.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@item.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this item from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @item.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :title, {:class=> "form-control", :size => "30x10"} %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :subject %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :subject, {:class=> "form-control", :size => "30x10"} %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <table class= "table-bordered">
    <tbody>
    <tr> 
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>

  </div>

  <div class=" form-actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

ERROR that i recieve that I can't figure out (btw it works without the REMOTE command)

```
/home/vic/projects/projects/app/views/projects/_formnew.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ...fer.append= form_for (@item, remote: true) do |f| @output... ... ^
```

Here is my Controller

```
def index
    @item = Item.new
    page = params[:page]
    if(page.blank? == false)
      next_page =(page.to_i) 
    else
      page = 0;
      next_page = page+1
    end
    @objects = Object.paginate(page: next_page, per_page: 20).order("created_at DESC")
    @next_link = next_page +1
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
      format.html {render :index}
      format.js {}
    end
  end
```

Comment: You place your `html` code in the `application.js` or it is typo?

Comment: It is a typo. Fixing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So Friends:

```
<%= form_for (@item, remote: true) do |f| %> is INCORRECT
<%= form_for @secret, remote: true do |f| %> is CORRECT
```

This was 6 hours of my life that will not return.